# How to use private_key.key / ssl_certificate.cer / ssl_certificate_INTERMEDIATE.cer uploaded from 1&1 IONOS and configure tomcat server <connector/>

Tags: ssl, tomcat, server, certificate, keystore

I used all the tutorials on the web to be able to generate a keystore and use it in the configuration of the tomcat 9 server under ubuntu

The three keys received from my site provider(IONOS) are:

private_key.key :

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

ssl_certificate.cer :

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

ssl_certificate_INTERMEDIATE.cer :

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

The connector is configured as below :

Question : how can i generate my keystore key to use with tomcat server.
Thanks in advance for your response and help

Comment: <Connector name="Secure"
port="8443" scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
sslImplementationName="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLImplementation">
    <SSLHostConfig sslProtocol="SSL">
        <Certificate type="RSA" certificateKeystoreFile="/tomcat/keystore.key"                      certificateKeyAlias="tomcat" certificateKeystorePassword="myPassword" 
                     certificateVerification="none"/>
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>

Comment: Your files are PEM files: `private_key.key` is the `certificateKeyFile`, `ssl_certificate.cer` is the `certificateFile` and `ssl_certificate_INTERMEDIATE.cer` is the `certificateChainFile`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replay, but my file extentions are ".key" and ".cer" not .pem, should i converts my files to pem files ?

Comment: The extensions used for private keys and certificates usually don't specify the format used (see [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/43697)). Your files start with `------BEGIN <something>`, therefore they are already in PEM format, no conversion is required.

Comment: Thanks, but still doesn't work :

Comment: My connector configuration is : <Connector name="Secure"
           port="8443"
           scheme="https"
           secure="true"
           SSLEnabled="true"
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol">
    <SSLHostConfig sslProtocol="SSL">
        <Certificate type="RSA"
                     certificateFile="conf/cert.pem"
                     certificateKeyFile="conf/privkey.pem"
                     certificateChainFile="conf/chain.pem" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>

Comment: I have copied the certificate files respectively in /opt/tomcat/conf/* (3files) and named them like bellow in connector descriptor.

Comment: When i access my site web with adding port number : https://www.mysite.fr:8443 it works and the navigator says that the connexion is secure but using : https://www.mysite.fr the navigator says that there is "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR" error.

Comment: tomcat statrup results : 06-Nov-2021 20:13:30.812 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
06-Nov-2021 20:13:30.825 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["https-openssl-nio-8443"]
06-Nov-2021 20:13:30.828 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [4835] milliseconds

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69864519/edit) your question and add the information in your comments: they will be more readable. You configured Tomcat to run on port `8443`, hence `https://mysite.fr:8443` works. The URL `https://mysite.fr` uses the default port `443`, which is not served by Tomcat, but by some other server that needs also to be configured to use your certificate.

Comment: All works fine, I have changed apache2 port from 80 to 1800 and then stops AVAST antivirus for 10 minutes and refreshing Chrome and Mozilla had access to my site.

Comment: @Piotr P. Karwasz  thanks for your help.